# In VSCODE how to run a task automatically when a source file is edited?

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

In **Visual Studio Code** (VSCode), working with a **mavenized Java web application**, which I call `sfeaapp` project.

What can be done so that every time a source or resource of that `sfeaapp` project is changed, the `mvn package` task is automatically executed?

I have defined the following task in `tasks.json`, but I don't know how to make it fire **automatically** when I edit and save a project file, for example a `.jsp`:

```json
    {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "auto package",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "mvn package -f C:\\VSCODE_PROJECTS\\sfeaapp\\pom.xml",
                "args": [],
                "group": "build",
                "presentation": {
                    "reveal": "always",
                    "panel": "shared"
                },
                "problemMatcher": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

The task `auto package` works fine if I launch it explicitly.

Comment: historically related: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2159, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139088, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the use of the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) you can re-define the keybinding for `Ctrl+S` to save the file and call the task after a small wait.

Add to your `keybindings.json`

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+s",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "interval": 1000,
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.files.save",
            { "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
              "args": "auto package" }
        ]
    },
    "when": "resourceDirname == /users/mememe/project/src"
}
```

Adjust the directory to the workspace directory path.